# passing javascript data to ruby methods

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs

Suppose I have {{data}} AngularJS data, that I can evaluate through

```
<%= j "{{data}}" %>
```

How can I pass this data to some ruby method inside my view (for example some helper method) ?

`<%= any_method({{data}}) %>`doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With AngularJS being client-side and Ruby/Rails being server-side, any data you want Ruby/Rails to process will have to be sent to the server.

Rails generates the page sent to the client, so sending data from Rails -> AngularJS is pretty straightforward, but if you try going the other direction it'll just be Angular talking to itself.

Simplest solution is just to serialize the data and POST it (via AJAX) to the server, have it processed and then have the result sent back (if needed).